# Getting "Ã—" instead of "×" in strings

Tags: python, windows, character-encoding

I have a file I am reading in to do some regex on, and one of the characters being matched in the source file is supposed to be an "×", but my program only sees it as "Ã—", which of course makes regex hard.

Googling enough has told me that this is a character encoding issue, an overlap between UTF-8 and Windows-1252. However, nothing I have found has told me how to fix the issue.

Potentially relevant information: The file I am reading from is a json, my code is in python 3.9, I am using Pycharm as an IDE, and I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ I am not sure how I could. It is literally just reading in a file that contains that character, and just reading it in wrong. Since it is an encoding issue, if someone else has whatever setting I need to change, it would run right, no?

Comment: Just share a code snippet where you are "*reading in a file*"… And pay your attention to https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Well, that is on me for not thinking that maybe the open function could specify an encoding. adding "encoding='utf-8'" to the open() function fixes my problem, thank you.